# Flutter onTextScaleFactorChanged error?

Tags: intellij-idea, text, window, flutter

I recently updated Flutter and my packages and now I'm getting this error that I didn't get before.  I've restarted IntelliJ and I'm getting all checks on my FlutterDoctor.

`NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Window' has no instance setter 'onTextScaleFactorChanged='.
    Receiver: Instance of 'Window'
    Tried calling: onTextScaleFactorChanged=Closure: () => void from Function 'handleTextScaleFactorChanged':.`

*** Added textAlign Code ***

```
class NumberOnesPageState extends State<NumberOnesPage> {List names = new List();
    List numbers = new List();
    List ids = new List();
    List vidImages = new List();


    void _handleJson(value) {


      Map myMap = value; //store each map
      var titles = myMap.values;
      for (var items in titles){
        names.add(items['vidTitle']);
        numbers.add(items['Value']);
        ids.add(items['vidId']);
        vidImages.add(items['vidImage']);

      }

    }
      final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();



      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              title: new Text('Number Ones',
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black
              ),),
            ),
            body: new Container(
              child: new Center(
                  child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Flexible(
                      child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                          query: fb.child('NumberOnes').orderByChild('Value'),
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          //sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
                          reverse: false,
                          itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot followerSnap,
                              Animation<double> animation, int Index) {
                            return new StreamBuilder<Event>(
                                stream: fb
                                    .child('NumberOnes')
                                    .orderByChild('Value')
                                    .onValue,
                                builder: (BuildContext context,
                                    AsyncSnapshot<Event> event) {
                                  switch (event.connectionState) {
                                    case ConnectionState.none:
                                      return new Card(
                                        child: new Text('Loading...',
                                            style: new TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                                      );
                                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                      return new Card(
                                        child: new Text('Awaiting Results...',
                                            style: new TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                                      );
                                    default:
                                      if (event.hasError)
                                        return new Card(
                                          child: new Text('Error: ${event.error}',
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                                        );
                                      else
                                        _handleJson(event.data.snapshot.value);
                                      return new InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                        onTap: (){
                                          Navigator.push(context,
                                              new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => new Video.VideoPage()));
                                          Video.id = ids[Index];
                                          Video.title = names[Index];
                                          Video.videoImage = vidImages[Index];

                                          },
                                        child: new Card(
                                          child: new Column(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                                              new Image.network(vidImages[Index]),
                                              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(3.0)),
                                              new Text('${numbers[Index]} MyFavKPopers Have Made This Their #1'),
                                              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(3.0)),
                                              new Text(names[Index],
                                              style: new TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  color: Colors.black),
                                              //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                  }
                                });
                          }))
                ],
              )),
            ));
      }
    }
```

Here is my textAlign Code.  It was not giving any errors before the upgrade and produced centered text as expected.  Not sure if it's even the code causing the error.

I've gone through an commented out all my `textAlign` functions.  Nothings working.  It has effectively locked me out of my codebase.

Comment: Can you provide a little context? Where is this method called?

Comment: @rainerwittman That's the thing. I'm not calling it anywhere. Not sure if it's an actual Flutter function. The closest text functions I'm using is `textAlign.center`

Comment: @CharlesJr Add your code please

Comment: @aziza Added textAlign.center code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the code you added to your question. I will do a little research ;)

Comment: Can you add a little more context to the code? maybe a small example class that reproduces the error? Which flutter and dart version are you working with?

Comment: Basically I built the text Widget. Ran it in ios. And it was fine. Updated Flutter and restarted IntelliJ and now it crashes with the above error. Please try to reproduce. It may be a bug.

Comment: Can you add the whole class, please?

Comment: @RainerWittmann I've added the whole class.  Please review.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to:

- Uninstall the application
- Run `flutter upgrade`
- Run `flutter doctor`
- Run `flutter run` via command line. (IntelliJ might have worked but I was already in the command line)

I'm not sure what caused the problem initially but this appeared to fix it for me.

Comment: Thanks.  My solution was to remove all text Alignment and Scale code and restart IntelliJ and run app.  Afterwards I put the lines of code back in and everything works as normal on both full restart and hot reload.  Not sure what the issue is either, it may need to be added to a github issue ticket.